# Is there any algorithm can find local minima of nonconvex objective function in guaranteed polynomial time?

Tags: algorithms, global-optimization

More precisely, The setting could be formulated as,

$min.  F_{\lambda}(p)$ over permutation matrices $P$

Here $F_{\lambda}(p)$=$\lambda *F_{0}(p)+(1-\lambda)F_{1}(p)$

where both $F_{0}(p)$ and $F_{1}(p)$ are **quadratic** (*Frobineous norm*) and $F_{0}(p)$ is convex, $F_{1}(p)$ is concave. Thus their combination can be neither convex nor concave.

The objective function comes from the paper ***A Path Following Algorithm for the Graph Matching Problem***, the ultimate goal is to find a good permutation matrix $P$ for the graph matching problem.

The idea of the author is briefly as follows,

1. relax the domain of the $F_{0},F_{1}$ to double stochastic matrices $D$
2. set $\lambda$ to 1. Since $F_{0}$ is convex, we can minimize $F_{0}$ efficiently to get the minimum $X^{cur}$
3. increase $\lambda$ iteratively to 1. In each iteration, optimize this $F_{\lambda}$ to a local minima using $X^{cur}$ as starting point.
4. update $X^{cur}$ to the newly local minima in step 3
5. when $\lambda=1$, since $F_{1}$ is concave, the local minima must be a permutation matrix.

In a theoretical perspective, the algorithm can be used as a way to solve the graph isomorphism problem. So I want to investigate in detail the running time of the algorithm. As the approximation graph isomorphism is NP-hard in general.

Thanks in advance.

[Link to the paper](http://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/path_following_pami.pdf)

Comment: You may wish to try out the CCCP Procedure (more generally, *d.c. programming*)

Comment: @Suvrit Is it possible to approximate the local minima with some constant factor with guaranteed polynomial time?

Comment: without additional structure, I don't think it will be possible in general to guarantee even reasonable non-constant factor approximations...; perhaps you could ask a more specific separate question with the exact $F_1$ and $F_2$ that you care about?

Comment: @Suvrit I updated my questions. Thx for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, without additional assumptions this will not be possible (barring P=NP).

In particular, from the (slightly edited) abstract of: K. G. Murty, S. K. Kabadi. [**Some NP-Complete problems in quadratic and nonlinear programming**, *Mathematical Programming*, 39(1987), 117-129](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02592948.pdf),

> In continuous variable, smooth, nonconvex nonlinear programming, we analyze the complexity of checking whether
>
> 1. a given feasible solution is not a local minimum, and
> 2. the objective function is not bounded below on the set of feasible solutions.
>
> We construct a special class of indefinite quadratic programs, with simple constraints and integer data, and show that checking (1) or (2) on this class is NP-complete. As a corollary, we show that checking whether a given integer square matrix is not copositive, is NP-complete.

Comment: Are you answering just the title or also the body of the question?

Comment: @usul I think for a specific choice of functions that the OP has, you can construct from the theory of the cited papers an example for which it is NP-complete to check local optimality (unless it is *a priori* somehow easy to prove that the Hessian is strictly positive definite at a stationary point that is a candidate for a local min)